# setting timer on the document viewing SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, excel, time-out, docx

We want to set a time out for viewing the document(Docx, pdf, excel files) in SharePoint based on the time.so, for example, we want the document to be activated for a certain user only for 3 hours after the user opens it for the first time and the time gets deducted for the next visit to the document, is it possible/?

Answer (score 1):

OOTB's approach doesn't meet your needs, sharePoint doesn't have a setting for viewing time.

Karthikeyan's approach may seem like a good choice, but it doesn't fully meet your needs.

According to my research, there are no corresponding steps in the workflow to calculate the last time you viewed a document and to calculate the time left to view the document.

Your needs may not be fully met.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have any OOTB approach to achieve this but we can give the workaround solution using SP workflow.

**Follow the below steps**

1.Trigger the workflow as per your need (Item Created/ Item Modified)

2.Add Impersonation step to the workflow

3.Add item level permission

4.Send an email notification to represent user/group

5.Pause the workflow for next 3 hours

6.Remove the item level permission for those users

7.Stop the workflow

**Ref :** https://truapps.portalfront.com/how-toset-sharepoint-item-level-permissions-based-on-column-or-field-values.html